# What should be the value of androidboot.mode?

Tags: android

Typically, it seems that androidboot.mode can take up one of the following values:

- lmp
- normal
- recovery
- charger
- any more ? (please enlighten me)

So the boot argument gets set by the bootloader (uboot in my case) and gets passed to the Kernel.
Now the confusion is, if uboot were to sense that the battery is low (charger mode) and the user were to request recovery mode, what should the value of androidboot.mode be in such a situation...? It seems like there are two possibilities "androidboot.mode=charger" OR "androidboot.mode=recovery". Would one take priority over the other ?

Would anyone have any thoughts on this ?

Thanks,
~vj

Answer (score 0):

The logical choice(to me, anyway) is charger mode. Trying to do anything in recovery with such a low battery state is asking for trouble. I know that's what I'd do if I were writing a bootloader.

You can easily test this by draining your battery and requesting recovery mode.